# Ubuntu Update Manager Shows 737 Updates. What do I do?

Tags: updates, shutdown, update-manager

I just got a computer but when I started it up I noticed it was really slow until it got going, Then the 737 updates popped up, I tried installing them but it shuts down half way through, How can i get these updates updated so my computer can run properly without constantly shutting down?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is in the command line run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Unsure based on the details in your post if you have attempted it, but give this a try to get past this 700 updates problem.

Comment: -Aspire-X1930:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: You need to run these commands as sudo like I listed.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: currently on a thirty-two bit

Comment: Google removed support for 32 bit chrome on March 1st. So you will either need to upgrade to 64 bit or switched to another browser and uninstall chrome.

Comment: I dont see how could help at all, i just need to speed up my computer by making some space on the drive. Not to mention that there are 737 updates that wont download..... I need help here please

Comment: Have you attempted to do the things I've told you? Uninstall Google chrome and run the apt-get commands I told you, that should update your packages.